# Roll back RPM package

Tags: linux, rpm

Is there any way to roll back a single package from `yum update`. I've noticed that the `rpm --rollback` switch is depreciated in SL linux 6.2.

There is also `yum history` however I would like to rollback one particular packages that it's not working (libvirt) however it was updated with `yum update` command so I would have to revert all the other packages what is not desired.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With `yum`, you get the `downgrade` option. Doing `yum downgrade <package name>` downgrade one version. That, and this [rather archaic way of rolling back via `rpm`](http://www.danieleocchipinti.com/blog-linux-php-lamp-web/linux/redhat-centos/rolling-back-yum-packages-centos-roll-back-after-installation).

However, as of `yum.3.2.25` you get the [context switch `history`, which also includes an `undo` function](http://www.if-not-true-then-false.com/2010/yum-history-list-info-summary-repeat-redo-undo-new/).

Comment: Is it possible to "undo" only one a specific package form the history if the update was done with "yum update" command and multiply packages were upgraded.

Comment: I'm not quite sure. I'll give a shot at a few things before outright saying *downgrade to correct version*